# Meshlab perimeter measurements of a STL file

Tags: meshlab, stl-format

I have a relatively simple question. I am using Meshlab to record simple linear (point-to-point) measurements on a 3D scan of a dental arch. I wish to take multiple measurements on a stl file to record the perimeter of a dental arch, this would require multiple linear measurements linked together. Is this possible on Meshlab? It sounds relatively simple to do however I am not sure if Meshlab or any other stl software can do it? I am willing to consider an alternative software if this is not possible on MeshLab.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get the perimeter of a selection.
After you have selected the FACES you need, use:

filters->Quality Measures and Computations->Compute Area/Perimeter of Selection.

the result will be printed in the LOG AREA of the layer panel.